# VS2012 - "Create table" or "show table data" menu option not shown in Server/Database Explorer

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Sql Server Data Tools to work with Visual Studio 2012 Express Release Candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707824/getting-sql-server-data-tools-to-work-with-visual-studio-2012-express-release-ca)

I have installed VS 2012 for Web and SQL Server 2012 and am opening a solution built in VWD 2010 and SQL 2008. The application runs fine and I am able to add/edit/delete records using the application. However, when i go to database explorer and right click on a table, i do not get the "Show table data" option anymore. When I right click on the database i do not get the "Create table" option either. This is a .mdf file. I have tried connecting to another SQL server (not the one on my local machine) and i get all those options, same thing with a localdb. Any idea why i wouldnt be getting these options for an SQL server installed on my local machine? Pipes/Shared/TCP are all enabled. Please help.

Comment: I'm confused. You say it's a .mdb file, which means it's Access. Yet you also say it's a local SQL database. Can you please clarify which you are using?

Comment: Just corrected, should have been .mdf, not .mdb, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think such options will only be available for Sql Databases, not for Access databases.

**Updated Answer**

Then I would recommend you to go for Sql Server Management Studio, free tool from Microsoft to Explore Sql Server Database. More flexible than built VS Plugin. Can do a lots of stuffs from there.

Its quite bulky in download (615Mb). here id the FileHippo link [Sql Management Studio 2012 Express](http://www.filehippo.com/download_sql_server_studio/)

I am not sure about what version you have installed in your machine, whether its express or standard. If its express then it will definitely work with the above link. But before downloading make sure you have express edition installed. Also I guess, other edition might come bundled with the Management Studio. You can install from there too.

Comment: This is an SQL 2012 express database.

Comment: Sorry, edited... should have been .mdf, not .mdb.

Comment: The new SSDT is much better for DB Development than Sql Server Management Studio. Declarative DB development is where its at!

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707824/getting-sql-server-data-tools-to-work-with-visual-studio-2012-express-release-ca) answer.

To summarize, SSDT and Visual Studio Express for Web are incompatible. You need to use the VS 2010 shell to use SSDT.

Comment: Where would i find this SQL Server Object explorer in Visual Studio for Web 2012?

Comment: It would be under the views menu, if SSDT is installed. If it isn't there, you're going to need to install SSDT manually. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2011/11/21/download-available-sql-server-data-tools-ctp4-ssdt.aspx)

Comment: Downloading now to try, although it would be nice if it would just work properly the way it did in 2010.

Comment: You are using VS for Web and trying to develop against a DB. At least SSDT is a free tool...

Comment: Installed SSDT successfully but cant seem to find it anywhere in Visual Studio for Web 2012. I have read that it should be under installed templates, but it is not there.

Comment: Can you not go View ---> SQL Server Object Explorer ? If you can see that then SSDT is installed. Once there you should be able to add a SQL Server. You should then be able to right click on any DB and create a project from that. If that doesn't work, check in your programs to see if SSDT for some reason installed a different VS shell for you. It should either integrate into your for Web version, or install its own shell.

Comment: Nope, it only shows "solution explorer", "team explorer", and "database explorer". I ran the SSDT installer and when it finished it said installation successful.

Comment: I would try [this](http://sqlproj.com/index.php/2011/11/ssdt-setup-from-sql-server-2012) blog post. If that doesn't work, I'm stumped.

Comment: i have microsoft visual studio 2010 listed in programs that shows the sql server explorer but that doesnt help me when in the VS 2012 IDE.