# Visual Studio 2012 - "Show Table Data" missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My "Show Table Data" has disappeared from Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012.

[image: [!vdd](http://oi39.tinypic.com/14agznk.jpg)]

I ran an update of Visual Studio, and the button disappeared after that. I've tried to uninstall the program, and do it all over again. No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043135/vs2012-create-table-or-show-table-data-menu-option-not-shown-in-server-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Control Panel and delete ALL MS SQL Programs, then reinstall.

Comment: Kind of a destructive solution. don't you think?

Comment: HI all, I know this an old post but I am struggling with the same in Visual Studio 2013 Professional and SQL Express. What do you mean with the above? Uninstall all SQL Products, then re-install Visual Studio? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I removed everything that had the name "Microsoft" and "SQL" together. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Got round to uninstalling all SQL product and re-installed Visual Studio. Now clicking on Movie.mdf throws the following error: "Connections to SQL Server database files (.mdf) require SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on the local computer." Do you think installing SQL Server 2012 Express would be a problem? Why does the latest Visual Studio version want to use such an old version of SQL Server Express?

Comment: Just realized the LocalDB part of Visual Studio 2013 installation failed. Need to sort that out first.

Comment: Update: It worked. What a process though to uninstall all SQL stuff, then install Visual Studio 2013, where the LocalDB installation failed. I downloaded that separately, installed and it worked. I haven't installed Server Express 2012 yet, hope it doesn't break everything once I do.....

Comment: Are you serious? I just did several uninstalls, installs, repairs to get SSMS working. I finally got it to work and now I have to go again? No way...

Comment: This is what I did two years ago to fix the problem. Not sure if you need to uninstall SSMS as I didn't have it installed at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in `Visual Studio 2015 Professional`.

I uninstalled *SSDT* (SQL Server Data Tools) and then downloaded and re-installed it from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Server Explorer pane, you can use the SQL Server Object Explorer (you need to install [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). You can then find SQL Server Explorer under `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Provider changed in the connection properties. Also check the user you are using to connect ( Username property ), as it must have select privileges on tables.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to delete all the SQL database-files that came with VS. I found that suggestion in another link, tried to delete them, and then installed VS again. Success!

Comment: Can you please share that link?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate 
then i downloaded 
*"Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013"*
from **Microsoft** website and installed it(must close visual studio before installation)
now open visual studio ,if it says any component is missing (for my case it said),then just repair visual studio from visual studio installation package.
After this Everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you don't have SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) installed on your computer. Follow the link below to download the file.
[SSDT Download Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx). After you download and install the file your "Show Data Table" should appear.

I would try this first before uninstalling any programs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in visual studio2015.
Download and install SQL Server Data Tools Preview in Visual Studio 2015 from below link.
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=785925&clcid=0x409