# Show Data Table missing on Visual Studio 2013 + SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

A similar topic as this has been discussed, but my problem lies with a different version of Visual Studio; I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) and I have progressed to the "Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller" section.

It says to open Server Explorer, expand Tables and right-click the Movies table and select **Show Table Data**. This option is missing (along with Add New Table, Add New Trigger, New Query and Open Table Definition). I only have Copy, Refresh and Properties.

Other posts talk about SQL Server Data Tools. On the page to download it there is a link to download "Download Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server Tooling", which goes to a page to download a trial copy of Visual Studio 2013.

It makes little sense to me. Am I suppose to have the option in 2013 Professional or not? I have also installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: I got it working following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736781/visual-studio-2012-show-table-data-missing. Had to uninstall all SQL related products, then re-install Visual Studio 2013. I haven't installed SQL Express yet and hope it doesn't break everything again once I do.

Comment: There has to be a better solution than that somewhere.  I'm in the middle of a critical project and don't have time to uninstall anything SQL related and reinstall VS 2013.

Comment: Try installing SSDT for Visual Studio 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to install SSDT for Visual Studio. Make sure that the Visual studio version matches.

The reason for me to have this problem: Because I reinstalled SQL server management, and this overwrote the "old" one (which is match VS).