# Visual Studio 2013 "Show Table Data" missing.

Tags: visual-studio

Pretty much same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736781/visual-studio-2012-show-table-data-missing). I'm hoping there might be a simpler solution in 2013.

[image]

Comment: Maybe installing SQL Server Data Tools（SSDT) might help. it is a very powerful tool.  

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Comment: That worked! Please enter it as an answer so I can accept. I hope some folks see this. That was so much easier than the solution in the other SO post (for 2012).

Comment: I added it as an answer. tnx :)

Comment: I love the idea of getting downvoted for bringing up a problem that has never before been on SO, has no solution on SO, and has a distinctly different solution to a similar problem in a slightly earlier version of the software. Just what would make this question better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SQL Server Data Tools（SSDT) will solve this issue as it enhance the visual studio relevant menus.

I recommend using as it is a very powerful tool.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Comment: Can you add some more detail?  Does simply installing the tool fix the problem?  Do you use the tool to fix the problem?

Comment: I added some details. is clear enough? do you like me to add some more info?